# Industrial kosher farming and shechita?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, slaughter-shochet-shecht

I understand that each animal slaughtered needs to be done with a special kind of knife and by a shochet. How might an industrial kosher farm operate without the need for an exorbitant amount of employees? Could there be a contraption that holds each animal, and a shochet pulls a level which controls several kosher knives?

Comment: there are acual industrial kosher meat plants, i am sure they are doing the most efficient job possible... just saying, you are not asking a theoretical question

Comment: @heshy is correct. I've been to the Falls Chicken farm / plant near Livingston Manor, NY. There are several chickens in fenced areas and a few in crates. When you enter the slaughtering house, they have (at that time) about 20 slaughterers around and each chicken is manually slaughtered. These guys are fast, and someone told me that they are expected to be "speedy" as part of the employment requirement. It takes about a minute or two per chicken, and it works like an assembly line. Once it's slaughtered, machinery can handle much of the remaining process such as cleaning and packaging, etc.

Comment: @DanF would any contraption to allow a shochet to slaughter more than one animal at a time be rendered un-Kosher?

Comment: @AviG it's theoretically fine, but practically it would be basically impossible to implement successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be true, there isn't a 'industrial kosher farmer', each animal has to be killed one by one, the animal cannot be afraid of dying, he cannot see other animals dying (as it would create fear on him). The person who will kill the animal has to do it when the animal is calm and prepared to die.

To kill all animals in a really really kosher way, it is necessary to make a large structure.

Some rabbi like Alon Anava do not eat from this 'industrial kosher seals'

Edit:

Fonts: Shiur of Rabbi Allon Anava --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6Kpbe5p31I

Comment: Please source at least something, here.

Comment: The second para is simply not true. In Eastern Europe *schochtim* worked one animal at a time. How was that not kosher? Also what does "prepared to die" mean for animal?

Comment: To be more precise --> (to kill VERY LARGE AMOUNT OF ANIMALS in a really kosher way, it is really a large structure).

well, about the source, here is a good Shiur of Rabbi Alon Anava (is a tough shiur): 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6Kpbe5p31I